# Status of Problems in 102 problems in mathematical logic

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, open-problems

Is there any location that records the current status of the problems in 102 problems in mathematical logic?  Or, better yet, serves as a status board for open problems in mathematical logic?  Mathoverflow is nice, but I'd leave it in a heartbeat for a variant that had an 'open problems' section which people could add problems to or mark them as solved as papers got published.

I almost just embarrassingly claimed to solve Q62 while writing up my solution to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422255/pi0-2-singleton-of-minimal-arithmetic-degree) question even though I should have remembered Harrington solved it.  Especially, as I agreed to write up beyond $\omega$ parts of his notes up at some point but haven't gotten to it yet.